# 403 Forbidden error for Google Analytics

Tags: jakarta-ee, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

**Problem Description**

I am using Google analytic Management API 2.4  to fetch Analytic's data.
Where I am getting following error

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"><error><domain>GData</domain><code>insufficientPermissions</code><internalReason>User does not have permission to perform this operation</internalReason></error></errors>
atcom.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:605)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1034)
at com.report.pojo.GoogleAnlytics2.printFirstAccount(GoogleAnlytics2.java:80)
at com.report.pojo.GoogleAnlytics2.main(GoogleAnlytics2.java:91)
```

I am using following code

```
public static DataQuery getBasicQuery(String tableId) throws MalformedURLException {
    DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL(DATA_URL));
    query.setIds(tableId);
    query.setStartDate("2011-07-12");
    query.setEndDate("2012-07-15");
    query.setDimensions("ga:hour");
    query.setMetrics("ga:visits,ga:bounces");
    query.setStringCustomParameter("key",API_KEY);
    return query;
}

public static void printData(String title, DataFeed dataFeed) {
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(dataFeed.getEntries().size());
    for (DataEntry entry : dataFeed.getEntries()) {
        System.out.println("\tHour: " + entry.stringValueOf("ga:hour"));
        System.out.println("\t\tVisits: " + entry.stringValueOf("ga:visits"));
        System.out.println("\t\tBounces: " + entry.stringValueOf("ga:bounces"));
        System.out.println("\t\tBounce rate: "+ entry.longValueOf("ga:bounces") / (double) entry.longValueOf("ga:visits"));
    }
    System.out.println();
}

BASE_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/"
DATA_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data"
```

I got some Google groups discussion pages,related to my issue([link1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-javascript-client/rfGp59wkG_Y/h6Tt-kcIGjAJ),[link2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-analytics-management-api/UA5kj9tcEkc/JA3IdHvS0bgJ) and [link3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-analytics-data-export-api/maa_fyjD2cM/bqiAzAZdDwAJ)) But I couldn't get Solution.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Google Analytics API in the Google APIs console? I had to do this last week as I was updating my python code.

If you haven't done this yet, log in at https://code.google.com/apis/console/, then set status to ON:

[image: google api console]

Comment: I log in and checked that Analytics services is On for this user , actually I am migrating my code from V2.3 to V2.4 as v2.3 gone to 403 while migrating I am using existing user account is it ok to use existing account or I have to create new account

Comment: I started hitting 404 errors last week with an old python library I was using. My upgrade was 3 parts: 1) Upgrade library code, specifically the url (replace https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data with new v2.4 url). 2) Update library authentication code to use Simple API Access key (also available from Google API console under API Access tab). 3) Enable Analytics API under Services tab. These 3 steps put me back in business. Sounds like you've done Steps 1 and 3. Step 2?

Comment: Thank you for reply ,actually I have changed the Data URL to https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data and Account URL as https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts?max-results=1 and I am also setting key as  DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL(DATA_URL));
query.setStringCustomParameter("key",API_KEY); my code showing me an account information like Account ID ,Account Name but throwing  exception for code  DataFeed basicData = myService.getFeed(basicQuery, DataFeed.class);

Comment: I just wanted to know that can we access data using API_KEY only or I need to give Oauth 2 information also ?

Comment: I have not upgraded my code to Oauth 2 yet. I am using the Simple API key (for browser apps, IIRC). Previously I had been authenticating with Google account username and password.

Comment: Just posted this on another comment, but this may be relevant here. This is a github commit made for the library I am using that upgraded it to v2.4: https://github.com/jsma/python-googleanalytics/commit/6be9b5ff8d6f353154ac556e16eafca130ab3d3e. It's in python, but it may be a helpful reference for your own code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15911/discussion-between-ashish-and-klenwell)